# how to calculate minute in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

im new in PHP. I just want to calculate between `$start_time & $finish_time`. 
But, when I set `$mstart` or `$mend` into `00-09`, the result always 7:00. Why it is happen?

And i just want the result in minute format.

Can you help me?

```
$hstart=17;
$mstart=10;
$start_time=date("H:i:s",strtotime($hstart.':'.$mstart));
echo $start_time;

echo "<br />";
$hend=20;
$mend=50;
$finish_time=date("H:i:s",strtotime($hend.':'.$mend));
echo $finish_time;

$tot_hour=($finish_time-$start_time);
echo "<br />";
echo $tot_hour;
```

Comment: What will happen for more than 24 hrs ?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find difference in `hours:minutes` also for more than 24 hrs which can't achieve by `date` function

```
<?php
    $hstart=17;
    $mstart=10;
    $start_time=($hstart*60)+($mstart);
    $hend=60;
    $mend=50;
    $finish_time=($hend*60)+($mend);
    $tot_in_minutes=$finish_time-$start_time;
    echo "Hrs : ".intVal($tot_in_minutes/60);
    echo "\n";
    echo "Minutes : ".$tot_in_minutes%60;
?>
```

Live Demo : https://eval.in/742647

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$hstart=17;
$mstart=10;
$sstart=10;
$start_time=strtotime($hstart.':'.$mstart.':'.$sstart);

$hend=20;
$mend=50;
$send=40;
$finish_time=strtotime($hend.':'.$mend.':'.$send);

$tot_hour=date("H:i:s",($finish_time-$start_time));
echo $tot_hour;
?>
```

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You want to get difference only in minutes so, you can achieve it like this.

```
$hstart=17;
$mstart=10;
$start_time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($hstart.':'.$mstart));
echo $start_time;

echo "<br />";
$hend=20;
$mend=50;
$finish_time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($hend.':'.$mend));
echo $finish_time;
echo "<br />";
echo round(abs(strtotime($finish_time) - strtotime($start_time)) / 60,2). " minute";
```